# Flipped dictionary not working correctly python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
import csv



def partytoyear():     #this function associate the party; to the year it was served#
    party_in_power = {}
    with open("presidents.txt") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            party = row[1]
            for year in row[2:]:
                party_in_power[year] = party
    new_dict = {}
    for k, v in party_in_power.items():
        new_dict[v] = k
    print(new_dict)  
partytoyear()
```

Original dictionary output:

```
'1961': 'Democrat', '1962': 'Democrat', '1963': 'Democrat', '1964': 'Democrat', '1965': 'Democrat', '1966': 'Democrat', '1967': 'Democrat', '1968': 'Democrat', '1969': 'Republican', '1970': 'Republican', '1971': 'Republican', '1972': 'Republican', '1973': 'Republican', '1974': 'Republican', '1975': 'Republican', '1976': 'Republican', '1977': 'Democrat', '1978':
```

I needed the keys and values flipped, so I added this code block:

```
new_dict = {}
    for k, v in party_in_power.items():
        new_dict[v] = k
    print(new_dict)
```

they flipped, but now I am only getting 2 results from the dictionary instead of the dozens. Heres the output:

```
{'Democrat': '2012', 'Republican': '2008'}
```

Any ideas? Is it not iterating through the for loop all the way?

Comment: What did you expect the outcome to be, given that a dictionary by definition maps each key to a *single* value?

Comment: A dictionary cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: ohh okay, so there is no possible way i can switch them?

Comment: @helloimstupidpythonstudent You can have values as lists: eg. `{'Democrat': ['1961', '1962' ..], 'Republican': ['2008', ..]}`

Comment: @helloimstupidpythonstudent You can't "switch" them if by switch you mean change each `k` -> `v` relationship to a `v` -> `k` relationship. You can however generate a list of keys that match each value, making two `v` -> `[k1, k2, ... kn]` relationships.

Comment: As I said, it depends what you actually want. You could, for example, process this into a dictionary with just the two keys, where the values are each a list of the corresponding years. But the key question, as with any about which data structure to use, is what you want to do with it.

Comment: Well I want the republicans and democrats separated and into different lists, because I need to associate republicans with certain years of statistics, and democrats with certain years of statistics as well. (I have another dictionary that has the year and a number associated with it)

Comment: You could use a pandas DataFrame and then use joins. But you need to show what is you final goal here. Otherwise it is very hard to guess the appropriate code.

Answer (score 1):

Since multiple keys map to the same value in the original dictionary, each key in the inverse dictionary will need to map to multiple values. A sensible way to do that is have a dictionary of lists:

```py
new_dict = { 'Democrat': [], 'Republican': [] }
for k, v in party_in_power.items():
    new_dict[v].append(k)
```

A slightly neater solution which doesn't hard-code the keys in the inverse dictionary is to use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

new_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in party_in_power.items():
    new_dict[v].append(k)
```

Comment: So its possible to have a dictionary within a list? So if i were to use the pop() function to pop all of the democrat values, it would still work?

Comment: This is two lists within a dictionary - not a dictionary within a list - but yes, you can have nested data structures like this. If you call `new_dict['Democrat'].pop()` then you will pop from the Democrat list.